# How do i get the submenus to show with a small window size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a basic menu bar that works on click. Everything works properly, but i noticed that if i make the browser window too small, the submenus open out of view and i can't scroll in the window to see them.

It is really easy to see what i am talking about if you view it on a mobile phone.
How would i auto add scroll bars to make sure that all my page's content can be seen?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2SC5G/6/
SEARCH > RESULTS > LATEST SMOKE RESULTS is the longest selection in this demo. in order to see what i an talking about, resize the browser and put the right border right next to the "Search" menu item.

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<!-- <LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="favicon.ico"> -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/tp_menu.js"></script></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="includes/tp_menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="z-index:100;width:100%;position:fixed;top:0;left: 0;min-width:1000px;">
        <div id="menuJQ">
            <ul class="menuJQ">
                <li class="parent"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="parent" href="#"><span>Product View</span></a> 
                    <div id="submenu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://www.google.com"><span>DevTask Search</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Active Machines</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="parent"><a href="#"><span>Request Tool</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Search</span></a>
                    <div id="submenu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://www.google.com"><span>DevTask Search</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Active Machines</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Integrity Query</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Internal DevTasks</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Results</span></a>
                                <div id="submenu">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#" target='_blank'><span>Latest Smoke Results</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" target='_blank'><span>Latest Smoke Results</span></a>
                                            <div id="submenu">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#"><span>DevTask Search</span></a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#"><span>Active Machines</span></a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#"><span>Integrity Query</span></a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Issues for Stability Team</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* menu::base */
.expand{
    display:block;
}
.collapse{
    display:none;
}
div#menuJQ {
    height: 46px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    width:auto;
    /*background: url(../includes/images/right2.png) repeat right 0;*/ 
    background-color:black; 
}

div#menuJQ ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
div#menuJQ ul.menuJQ {
    padding-right: 0px;
}

div#menuJQ li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    z-index: 9;
    width: auto;
}

div#menuJQ ul ul li {
    z-index: 9;
}
div#menuJQ li div {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 39px;
    left: -18px;
    -left: 4px;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.5s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition-delay: 0.5s; /* Opera */
    width: 180px;
      margin: 0px 0 0 -4px;
    padding: 0; 
    background: url(../includes/images/submenu-top.png) no-repeat 0px 0;
    -background: url(../includes/images/submenu-top.gif) no-repeat 0px 0; 
}
div#menuJQ ul ul { /*submenu*/
    display:none;
      z-index: 12;
      width: 180px;
    padding: 0px 0px 12px 0px;
    -padding: 0px 0px 3px 0px;    
    /*background: url(../includes/images/submenu-bottom.png) no-repeat 0px bottom;*/
    background-color:black;
    -background: #E4E4E2 none;        
    margin: 14px 0 0 0;   
    -margin: 5px 0 0 0;      
}
div#menuJQ li > div {
    visibility: visible;
}

div#menuJQ a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 38px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 38px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;
    padding-right:5px;
    text-align:center;
}
div#menuJQ span {
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font: normal 13px Tahoma;
    background: none;
    line-height: 38px;  
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 0;
    text-align: center;
}

/* menu::level1 */
div#menuJQ a {
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
    line-height: 38px;
    height: 46px;
    _margin-right: 1px;
    background: none;
    font-weight:bold;    

}
div#menuJQ span {
    font-weight:bold; 
}
div#menuJQ a:hover{
    background-image: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: right -1px;    
    -background: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.gif) repeat-x right -1px; 
}
div#menuJQ li.current a,
div#menuJQ ul.menuJQ>li:hover>a {
    background-image: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: right -1px;  
    -background: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.gif)  repeat-x right -1px; 
}
div#menuJQ a:hover span{
      color: #ff9900;
}   
div#menuJQ ul.menuJQ>li:hover>a span {
      color: #ff9900;
}
div#menuJQ li {}
div#menuJQ li.last { background: none; }


/* menu::level2 */
div#menuJQ ul ul li {
    background-image: url(../includes/images/sep-sub.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul li:hover {
    background-image: url(../includes/images/sub-item-hover.gif);
    background-color: #717171;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul a {
      color: #ff9900;   
    height: auto;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 13px;
    z-index: -1;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 0px;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 166px;
    margin: 0 0px 0 13px;
    background: none;
}

div#menuJQ ul ul a span {
    color: #ff9900; 
      padding: 0 3px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin:0;    
}
div#menuJQ li.current ul a,
div#menuJQ li.current ul a span {
    background: none;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul a:hover {
    background: none;
  color: #fff;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul a:hover span {
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul a.parent {
  background: url(../includes/images/submenu-pointer.png) no-repeat right top;
  -background: url(../includes/images/submenu-pointer.gif) no-repeat right top;  
  margin-right: -1px;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul a.parent span {
  padding-right: 26px;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul a.parent:hover {
  background: url(../includes/images/submenu-pointer-hover.gif) no-repeat right top;
  -background: url(../includes/images/submenu-pointer.gif) no-repeat right top;  
}
div#menuJQ ul ul a.parent:hover span {
}
div#menuJQ ul ul span {

    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul li.last { background: none; }
div#menuJQ ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
}

/* menu::level3 */

div#menuJQ ul ul div {
      width: 180px;
      padding: 0;
    background: url(../includes/images/subsubmenu-top.png) no-repeat 0px 0;
    -background: url(../includes/images/subsubmenu-top.gif) no-repeat 0px 0;      
    margin: -32px 0 0 198px !important;
    margin: -32px 0 0 176px;
}
div#menuJQ ul ul ul {
    padding: 11px 0px 9px 0px;  
    margin: 20px 0 0 0; 
}
div#menuJQ ul ul div li {
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
}

/* lava lamp */
div#menuJQ li.back {
    background: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    -background: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.gif) no-repeat 0 0;    
    width: 5px;
    height: 46px;
    z-index: 8;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px 0 0 0;
}


div#menuJQ li.back .left {
    padding:0;
    width:auto;
    background: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.png) repeat-x right 0;
    -background: url(../includes/images/selected-sub.gif) repeat-x right 0;     
    height: 46px;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menuJQ > ul li').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            $('ul:first', this).show();
    });

    $('#menuJQ > ul li').mouseleave(function() {
        $('ul', this).hide();
    });

    $('#submenu > ul li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = (this).href;
        // var test = (this).href;
        // alert(test);
    });
});
```

Comment: Float the menu items at certain window size using media-queries. That looks like a lot of code for such a simple menu though...

Comment: This is an example of why people start off with a css framework like http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/. It will save you time in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all of the CSS that you wrote into a media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {

    .expand{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

This will make it only work when the screen is wider than 900px.  You can change that number of pixels.

Now write the CSS that you want only for mobile, outside the media query. Styles in the mdeia query will overwrite, but only when the condition is met.

If you want a widget for lists, you can visit my page: 
http://instancia.net/jquery-plugin-mobile-list/
Shrink your browser width to see the widget. Zip file in page.

Comment: @elclanrs The html is actually longer and more detailed, but i shortened it for readability and simplicity in the example. I forgot to shorten the css.